# too few template-parameter-lists error in full class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm learning about template specializations and I wrote an example to better understand how it all works. 
I'm reading C++ template complete guide.
The example is a bit contrived, so be advised it's just for learning purposes:

I define the primary template:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT(msg)          std::cout << (msg)
#define PRINTLN(msg)        PRINT(msg) << std::endl;

/***** primary template ****/
template <typename T1>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename T2>
    struct B;
};

template <typename T1>
template <class T2>
struct A<T1>::B
{
    template <typename T3>
    struct C;
};

template <typename T1>
template <typename T2>
template <typename T3>
struct A<T1>::B<T2>::C
{
    void MemberFunction();
    template <typename F>
    void MemberFunctionTemplate();
};

template <typename T1>
template <typename T2>
template <typename T3>
void A<T1>::B<T2>::C<T3>::MemberFunction()
{
    PRINTLN("1");
}

template <typename T1>
template <typename T2>
template <typename T3>
template <typename F>
void A<T1>::B<T2>::C<T3>::MemberFunctionTemplate()
{
    PRINTLN("2");
}
```

then I fully specialize the nested struct C:

```
/**** explicit (full) class template specialization for struct C ****/
// template <> for each enclosing class template
template <>
template <>
template <>
struct A<float>::B<int>::C<int>
{
    template <typename T>
    void MemberFunctionTemplate();
    void MemberFunction();  // definition in specialization.cpp
    struct D;
};

// no template <>
template <typename T>
void A<float>::B<int>::C<int>::MemberFunctionTemplate()
{
    PRINTLN("4");
}

// no template <>
struct A<float>::B<int>::C<int>::D   // ERROR!
{
    static void StaticMemberFunction();
};
```

since a full specialization is not a template anymore, I can define out of class members without the `template <>` prefix syntax. I put member function definitions in a cpp file (so I don't break the ODR), and I define my nested struct D inside the header file for the compiler to see.

But I get an error from the compiler when the struct D definition is first seen:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
specialization.hpp:94:34: error: too few template-parameter-lists
 struct A<float>::B<int>::C<int>::D
                                  ^
In file included from specialization.cpp:1:0:
specialization.hpp:94:34: error: too few template-parameter-lists
 struct A<float>::B<int>::C<int>::D
```

It doesn't make sense to me, since I'm defining the struct correctly out of its enclosing (specialized) class. I tried adding a template <> but of course it's wrong.
If I try to fully specialize class A and add a struct D (like I'm trying to do in full class template specialization of struct C), it all works. Why?

Comment: gcc 9.1.1 seems to compile the sample code without any issues. Either your compiler, or my compiler, has a bug.

Comment: even in Visual Studio 2017  I get:

Error C2906 'A<float>::B<int>::C<int>::D': explicit specialization requires 'template <>'

but if I add template <> it complains (of course)

Comment: Clang 8.0.0 compiles [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H13bSadbKWk9cTec).

Comment: Who told you that "*a full specialization is not a template anymore*"? A template is not a template only after it's been instantiated.

Comment: @rustyx I read it in C++ template complete guide. When a class template is fully specialized its definition is not a template anymore (it's more like a ordinary class definition) so out of class member definitions cannot be prefixed by template <>

Comment: @rustyx: “anymore” is at best colloquial, but it’s true that an explicit specialization is not a template (and can’t even be templated via an enclosing class template).